# не работают python скрипты в браузере

Tags: python, python-3.6

freebsd, python3,  на сервере есть каталог /home/admin/cgi-bin

захожу в /home/admin/ там разворачиваю http сервер:

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

по умолчанию он использует 8000 порт, захожу по ip:8000 и мне выводится каталог где лежит file.py , когда перехожу по ip:8000/cgi-bin/file.py мне выводится белый экран и никаких ошибок....

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env python3

import cgi

print ('ffff')
```

это содержимое файла

хотя в консоли если набираю python3 file.py то нормально показывает - проверка
в чём может быть причина?

Comment: Возьмите пример Python-файла из вопроса-дубликата — он заработает и выведет не белый экран

Comment: пробовал не работает

Comment: А у меня работает. Покажите скриншот, текст ошибки в консоли, что как запускаете и так далее, а то вопрос не переоткроют. И про chmod не забывайте

Comment: путь к интерпритатору был неверный, /local/ было лишнее

Comment: а как теперь http.server на автозапуск поставить в freebsd?

Comment: Так же, как и любую другую программу на автозапуск в freebsd? Думаю, в документации freebsd должно быть что-нибудь написано по этому поводу

Comment: вот пример автозагрузки самбы: samba_server_enable="YES"

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/ru_RU.KOI8-R/books/handbook/configtuning-starting-services.html

Comment: а как мне добавить в файл автозагрузки тот же CGIHTTPServer питона версии 2.7